# $F$ is a finite field whose order is a power of 3, then $\sqrt{-1} \in F$ if and only if $\sqrt[4]{-1} \in F$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, extension-field

If $F$ is a finite field whose order is a power of 3, then $\sqrt{-1} \in F$  if and only if  $\sqrt[4]{-1} \in F$.

My attempt:

Let $\alpha = \sqrt[4]{-1}$.

The converse direction is straightforward, in other words, if $\alpha \in F$ then $\alpha^2 = \sqrt{-1} \in F$.

For the other direction, if $\alpha^2 \in F$, can I adjoin $F$ with $\alpha$, to have $F(\alpha)$ and since $F(\alpha^2) \subset F(\alpha)$ then

$|F(\alpha):F| = |F(\alpha):F(\alpha^2)||F(\alpha^2):F|$.

I am not sure if this leads to the required result.

Comment: If $4|3^n-1$, then $n$ is even, so $8|3^n-1$

Comment: @Eric is that related to the problem? Can you give more details?

Comment: Multiplicative group is cyclic of order $3^n-1$. Let $g$ be generator.  $(-1)^{1/k}$ is in $F$ iff $2k$ divides $3^n-1$ by (one way) considering $g^{(3^n-1)/2k}$ and (other way) using Lagrange’s Theorem.

Comment: @Eric Thank you for the hint. I tried to use the hint but still couldn't figure out

Comment: @Eric I think I got it. Thank you for the hint and the clarifications